# Configurable product changes the custom attribute when we change the colour In Magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, custom-attributes

I have created the configurable product, changes the custom attribute value when we change the color variation.

[image]

Comment: How many variation attribute for the product?

Comment: suppose if i change the colour then it display the custom attribute of simple product.

Comment: Is it possible to post screenshot of your product page?